# PostgreSQL COPY additional header - footer rows in csv

Tags: postgresql, csv, header, copy, footer

I want to COPY a couple of csv-Files to my database.
However they have additional header / footer rows containing information, which is not in the csv format.
In example:

```
Version: xxxxxxxxx
Start
Column1;Column2;Column3
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
End
Rows of Data: 3
```

Is there a way of skipping the additional rows / columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file structure is always the same - in your case first two and last two invalid - you can use `FROM PROGRAM` and fix the file with `head` and `tail` on the fly:

```
\COPY t FROM PROGRAM 'tail -n +3 file.csv | head -n -2' CSV DELIMITER ';' HEADER;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Since its a fixed format it will help for sure.